# How do I store this set of parameters in an array and then output it?

Tags: powershell, parameters

Basically, I need to add a few parameters into an array to store them and then output them with " (Nameof parameter) Count:" in front of them. I'm just confused on how to actually do this.

The parameters have used a loop to go through a file and count the amount of times a certain word is present.

The names are $Hi $Bye $Yes $No

I was thinking it would just be

```
                          $Array = @($Hi, $Bye, $Yes, $No)
                                $Array[0]
                                $Array[1], etc...
```

But then how do I actually put "(Name of parameter) Count:" in front of it?

If there is a better way to do this, I am open to suggestions! I am new to powershell, so thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the variables `$Hi`, `$Bye` etc contain.. Are these arrays of _found words_ or do they already contain a numeric value for the number of times the words 'Hi', 'Bye' etc. were found in a file??

Comment: @Theo Hey sorry! I thought I included it, but I clearly didn't. They contain the numeric value of the number of times they were found. I did get the answer though below, thanks for stopping by to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an array you would need to exclusively name it. So for your Output you'd just hardcode it like this:

```
Write-Output "Hi Count: $Array[0]"
```

Using a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) might be more like what you're looking for.

```
$ht = @{"Hi" = $Hi; "Bye" = $Bye; "Yes" = $Yes; "No" = $No}
```

If you just output the hash table you will ge an output that is just missing the "Count". If you need that you could use `$ht.GetEnumerator()` and a For-Each loop. That way you will have `$_.Key` and `$_.Value` available.